# Rewriting $a= \tan^{-1}\left( \frac{b/c - \cos \gamma}{\sin(\gamma) } \right) - \gamma$ as $\gamma = \cdots$

Tags: trigonometry

I have this formula and I want it to be $\gamma = \dots$

$$a= \tan^{-1}\left(  \frac{b/c - \cos \gamma}{\sin(\gamma) } \right) - \gamma$$

while $a$, $b$ and $c$ are constants.

I tried several ideas but none worked, any ideas?

Comment: What about $\gamma=\arctan\left(\frac{b/c-\cos\gamma}{\sin\gamma}\right)-a$?

Comment: the thing is I am trying to use it in matlab so I have no information about $\lambda$

Comment: $tan( a+ \gamma) =(  \frac{(b/c - cos(\gamma))}{sin(\gamma) } )$  ??? after that it's simply an equation you play with trigo formulas to simplify ...eexpressing everything in term og tan(\gamma)

Comment: I don't understand your comment. Did I or did I not express $\gamma$ as a functions of $a$, $b$, and $c$?

Comment: No because I want $\gamma = (not function of \gamma)$ because I know $a$,$b$ and $c$ only

Comment: Where does $\lambda$ com into it? You can write $tan(\gamma +a)$ out using double angle formula. With some messing around I expect you can write it as a polynomial in $sin(\gamma)$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $(*)$ be the initial equation.

$$ (*) \Leftrightarrow \tan(a+\gamma)=\frac{\frac{b}{c}-\cos\gamma}{\sin \gamma}$$

$$ \Leftrightarrow (\sin\gamma)(\tan (a+\gamma))+\cos \gamma=\frac{b}{c}$$

$$\Leftrightarrow \sin \gamma\frac{\tan a +\tan \gamma}{1-\tan a \tan \gamma}+\cos \gamma = \frac{b}{c}$$

Now, I'll use $ u = \tan \frac{\gamma}{2}$

Then,

$$ \cos \gamma = \frac{1-u^2}{1+u^2}, \sin \gamma = \frac{2u}{1+u^2} \text{ and } \tan \gamma = \frac{2u}{1-u^2}$$

The equation becomes ($A=\tan a$ and $R=\frac{b}{c} $)

$$ (*) \Rightarrow \frac{2u}{1+u^2}\frac{A+\frac{2u}{1-u^2}}{1-A\frac{2u}{1-u^2}}+\frac{1-u^2}{1+u^2}= R$$

After simplification, you would get an equation in $u$:

$$ (R+1)u^4+2ARu^3+2u^2+2ARu+(1-R)=0 $$

$$\Leftrightarrow (u^2+1)((R+1)u^2+2ARu+1-R)=0$$

By solving the quadratic equation and using $ u =\tan\frac{\gamma}{2}$ you should obain an expression for $\gamma$.

You'll need to check yourself, but what I got was under favorable conditions is

$$ \gamma = 2\arctan (\frac{-2\frac{b}{c}\tan a+\sqrt{(\frac{b}{c})^2(\tan^2 a+1)-1}}{2(\frac{b}{c})+1})$$

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I understood correctly what you want to do but here is how I tried... I set $k=\frac{b}{c}$ for simplification.

$$a= \tan^{-1}\left(  \frac{k - \cos(\gamma)}{\sin(\gamma) } \right) - \gamma$$

$$ \tan (\gamma+a)=\frac{k-\cos(\gamma)}{\sin(\gamma)}$$

$$ \frac{\tan(\gamma)+\tan(a)}{1-\tan(a)\tan(\gamma)}=\frac{k - \cos(\gamma)}{\sin(\gamma) }$$

Use the formulas for $\sin$, $\tan$ and $\cos$ in terms of $\tan\left(\frac {\gamma}{2}\right) $

Normally you will get an equation in $\tan\left(\frac{\gamma}{2}\right)$, that's not going to be that simple.

Answer (score 1):

The arctangent function has range $(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$, so if we begin by rewriting the equation as

$$\gamma+a=\arctan\left(b/c-\cos\gamma\over\sin\gamma \right)$$

we see that any solutions we get require $-\pi/2\lt\gamma+a\lt\pi/2$.  This suggests making a convenient change of variable, $v=\gamma+a$, so that the equation becomes

$$v=\arctan\left(b/c-\cos(v-a)\over\sin(v-a) \right)=\arctan\left(b/c-\cos v\cos a-\sin v\sin a\over\sin v\cos a-\cos v\sin a \right)$$

Taking the tangent on both sides turns this into

$${\sin v\over\cos v}={b/c-\cos v\cos a-\sin v\sin a\over\sin v\cos a-\cos v\sin a}$$

or

$$\sin^2v\cos a-\sin v\cos v\sin a=(b/c)\cos v-\cos^2v\cos a-\cos v\sin v\sin a$$

which simplifies to

$$\cos a=(b/c)\cos v$$

Thus

$$\cos v={c\cos a\over b}$$

The requirement $-\pi/2\lt v\lt\pi/2$ implies $0\lt\cos v\le1$, so we see that we must have $0\lt {c\cos a\over b}\le1$ in order to have any solutions, in which case we get two solutions:

$$\gamma=\pm\arccos\left(c\cos a\over b\right)-a$$